# NestJS: How to register transient and per web request providers

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am working on a multi-tenant application using NestJS and offering my API through their GraphQL module. I would like to know how I could tell NestJS to instantiate my providers per web request. According to their documentation providers are singleton by default but I could not find a way to register transient or per request providers.

Let me explain a specific use case for this. In my multi-tenant implementation, I have a database per customer and every time I receive a request in the backend I need to find out for which customer it is so I need to instantiate services with a connection to the right database.

Is this even possible using NestJS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the release of nest.js 6.0, [injection scopes](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#scopes) were added. With this, you can choose one of the following three scopes for your providers:

- **SINGLETON**: Default behavior. One instance of your provider is used for the whole application
- **TRANSIENT**: A dedicated instance of your provider is created for every provider that injects it.
- **REQUEST**: For each request, a new provider is created. Caution: This behavior will bubble up in your dependency chain. Example: If UsersController (Singleton) injects UsersService (Singleton) that injects OtherService (Request), then both UsersController and UsersService will automatically become request-scoped.

#### Usage

Either add it to the `@Injectable()` decorator:

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class UsersService {}
```

Or set it for custom providers in your module definition:

```
{
  provide: 'CACHE_MANAGER',
  useClass: CacheManager,
  scope: Scope.TRANSIENT,
}
```

---

### Outdated Answer

As you can see in this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/953#issuecomment-413348496), nestjs does not yet offer a built-in solution for request-scoped providers. But it might do so in the near future:

> Once async-hooks feature (it is still experimental in node 10) is
>   stable, we'll think about providing a built-in solution for
>   request-scoped instances.

Comment: Yes I have seen a lot of discussion about, in the meantime I had to swith to "single database with tenant identifier" in order to keep using NestJS which I think is great  but it is still missing this which in my opinion is key

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with similar issue, and one way to achieve this is to use `node-request-context` module as a global request register, that will give you the request context. So you will not have separate service instances, but you can ask this static register to give you request specific instance/connection.

https://github.com/guyguyon/node-request-context

Create simple context helper:

```
import { createNamespace, getNamespace } from 'node-request-context';
import * as uuid from 'uuid';

export class RequestContext {

    public static readonly NAMESPACE = 'some-namespace';
    public readonly id = uuid.v4();

    constructor(public readonly conn: Connection) { }

    static create(conn: Connection, next: Function) {
        const context = new RequestContext(conn);
        const namespace = getNamespace(RequestContext.NAMESPACE) || createNamespace(RequestContext.NAMESPACE);

        namespace.run(() => {
            namespace.set(RequestContext.name, context);
            next();
        });
    }

    static currentRequestContext(): RequestContext {
        const namespace = getNamespace(RequestContext.NAMESPACE);
        return namespace ? namespace.get(RequestContext.name) : null;
    }

    static getConnection(): Connection {
        const context = RequestContext.currentRequestContext();
        return context ? context.conn : null;
    }

}
```

The `conn` instance parameter is your connection, feel free to put there other request specific dependencies. Also the `id` there is just for debugging, no real need to use `uuid` module as I did.

Create middleware wrapper (this allows you to use DI here):

```
@Injectable()
export class ContextMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

  constructor(private readonly connectionManager: ...) { }

  resolve(...args: any[]): MiddlewareFunction {
    return (req, res, next) => {
      // create the request specific connection here, probably based on some auth header...
      RequestContext.create(this.connectionManager.createConnection(), next);
    };
  }

}
```

Then register new middleware in your nest application:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {});
app.use(app.get(RequestLoggerMiddleware).resolve());
```

And finally the profit part - get the request specific connection anywhere in your application:

```
const conn = RequestContext.getConnection();
```

Comment: This is definitely in the right direction, thanks for sharing!

Comment: The node-request-context is not ready for production due to asynchronous api

Answer (score 0):

NestJS has a build-in request-scope dependency injection mechanism
https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes
but it has serious drawbacks according to the documentation:

> Scope bubbles up the injection chain. A controller that depends on a request-scoped provider will, itself, be request-scoped.

> Using request-scoped providers will have an impact on application performance. While Nest tries to cache as much metadata as possible, it will still have to create an instance of your class on each request. Hence, it will slow down your average response time and overall benchmarking result. Unless a provider must be request-scoped, it is strongly recommended that you use the default singleton scope.

Recently I have created request-scope implementation for NestJS free from bubbling up the injection chain and performance impact.

https://github.com/kugacz/nj-request-scope

To use it first you have to add import of RequestScopeModule in the module class decorator:

```
import { RequestScopeModule } from 'nj-request-scope';

@Module({
    imports: [RequestScopeModule],
})
```

Next, there are two ways of request-scope injection:

1. Inject express request object into class constructor with NJRS_REQUEST token:

```
import { NJRS_REQUEST } from 'nj-request-scope';
[...]
constructor(@Inject(NJRS_REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {}
```

2. Change class inject scope to request-scope with @RequestScope() decorator:

```
import { RequestScope } from 'nj-request-scope';

@Injectable()
@RequestScope()
export class RequestScopeService {
```

You can find example implementations in this repository: https://github.com/kugacz/nj-request-scope-example