# NestJS/ Is a middleware instantiated as a singleton?

Tags: nestjs, middleware

I'm quite new to NestJS, so if I overlook something obvious, please forgive me.

Now I'm implementing a simple logger which logs request and response.
In NestJS, you can put a middleware only before routing, so my middleware overwrite `res.write` and `res.end` so that response chunks will be pushed to an array in the middleware.

```
export class Logger implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const originalResWrite = res.write;
    const originalResEnd = res.end;

    const chunks = [];

    res.write = (...chunk) => {
      chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk[0]));
      originalResWrite.apply(res, chunk);
    };
    res.end = (...chunk) => {
      if (chunk[0]) {
        chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk[0]));
      }

      const body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString("utf8");

      console.log({
        requestBody: req.body,
        responseBody: JSON.parse(body) || body || {},
      });

      originalResEnd.apply(res, chunk);
    };
  }
}
```

However, if this middleware is instantiated as a singleton and shared by all requests--like Django middleware--, `chunks` Array will receive chunks from several streams, and the log will be totally messed up.

So, the problem is, how comsumer.apply instantiate a midddleware.

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(Logger)
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

In  NestJS, is a middleware instantiated as a singleton, or instantiated each time request comes?
If you would answer my question, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default providers are singleton in Nestjs, however, you can define the scope for your middleware using the options in the `Injectable` decorator.
So you can add this before your middleware class definition

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
```

Check out this [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#provider-scope) in the documentation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679456/nestjs-how-to-register-transient-and-per-web-request-providers) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Please note that making your providers request scoped will make the dependency injection sub-tree request scoped as well, meaning that new instances will be created for every request. This hurts performance significantly. Just pointing this out in case anyone doesn't already know.

Comment: I understood that setting injection scope: REQUEST can hurt performance, so you should avoid it when it's unnecessary. Is my following understanding correct? : if a logger middleware is implemented as a singleton, the state of the middleware(in this case, chunks array) will be shared by all requests. As a result. the log will be messed up. So I need to set injection scope: REQUEST in this case.

Comment: While the middleware i.e. the class itself is a singleton and will be shared across requests, the chunks array itself is a local scope variable inside the `use()` method, this method will be called separately for each request, as far as I know. So unless you suspect unusual behavior, I wouldn't worry about the state getting mixed up between requests.